# Reading a text file and sorting by extension using python

Tags: python, loops, parsing

I would like to read a text file using python. If a line with .cpp found, process it **first** and then if a line with .java extension found, process it **second**.

Test.py is my sample code, using a for loop, it will read Test.txt and then it will process COMPILE_JAVA() method first and then it will execute COMPILE_CPP() method.

Test.txt

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/a/Hello.java
/home/jenkins/workspace/b/Hello.cpp
/home/jenkins/workspace/b/Hello1.cpp
```

Test.py

```
for f in files:
    ACTION1 = False
    ACTION2 = False
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
        for line in (file):
            if ACTION1 is False and ('.cpp' in line ):
                COMPILE_CPP()
                ACTION1 = True
            elif ACTION2 is False and '.java' in line:
                COMPILE_JAVA()
                ACTION2 = True
                break
```

Comment: Exactly what do you want to ask about?? Plz be more specific.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm trying to read a text file, if .cpp found in the entire text file, process it first and then process rest of the lines with different file extension.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can sort the list you read from `test.txt` by extension using `os.path.splitext`:

```
import os

with open(f, 'r') as file:
    sorted_files = sorted(file, key=lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1])
    for line in sorted_files:
        # rest of the code
```

Given

```
l = ['/home/jenkins/workspace/a/Hello.java',
     '/home/jenkins/workspace/b/Hello.cpp',
     '/home/jenkins/workspace/b/Hello1.cpp']
```

Then running `sorted(l, key=lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1])` returns:

```
['/home/jenkins/workspace/b/Hello.cpp',
 '/home/jenkins/workspace/b/Hello1.cpp',
 '/home/jenkins/workspace/a/Hello.java']
```

Explanation:

`os.path.splitext` returns a tuple (root, ext), e.g. `os.path.splitext("dir/myfile.txt")` returns `("dir/myfile", ".txt")`, so `lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1]` returns the second part (`.txt`).

This is then passed as an argument to the `sorted` function, so the list gets sorted alphabetically by extension.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, can you please explain what exactly these line is doing? sorted(l, key=lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1])

Comment: @Mihir I've added an explanation to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help? I used bubble sort to sort the extensions.

```py
row_list = []
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        row_list.append(line)

for i in range(1, len(row_list)):
    for j in range(len(row_list), i, -1):
        ext1 = row_list[j-1].split(".")[1]
        ext2 = row_list[j].split(".")[1]
        if ext1 > ext2:
            row_list[j-1], row_list[j] = row_list[j], row_list[j-1]

with open("output_file.txt", "w") as file:
    for row in row_list:
        file.write(f"{row}\n")
```

Comment: Thank you Filip.